# Rendering React components via object literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Are there any downsides performance wise, to render react components like these options?

And more specific about option #1:

- Would it be better to place the icons object outside of the function, maybe even outside of the component?

```
// option #1
const renderIcon = iconName => {
   const icons = {
       iconX: <IconX />,
       iconY: <IconY />,
       iconZ: <IconZ />,
   };
   return icons[iconName];
};

return <div>{renderIcons('iconX')}</div>


// option #2
const icons = useMemo(() => ({
    iconX: <IconX />,
    iconY: <IconY />,
    iconZ: <IconZ />,
}), [props.iconName]);

return <div>{icons[props.iconsName]}</div>
```

Comment: You don't have to pass `props.iconName` to the dependency array. It would be better to move this object outside of the component entirely.

Comment: With that approach, you end up having all of those icons in one client-side bundle, whereas if you're concerned about the performance, you'd be much better off [lazy-loading](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) them when required. Furthermore, you should be carefull with `useMemo()` since under certain circumstances you may end up [loosing](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback) performance-wise.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thanks, but can you explain what are the benefits of moving this outside?

Comment: The object is created once instead of every render which happens now.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of performance, there is a downside since the functions of all components will be executed, including components that are not rendering. Although readability is worse, from a performance perspective it would be better to do a switch or ternary rendering.